# Print Statement executing twice Python

Tags: python

When a user enters an input and if it is not available, the print executes twice
How do I fix it???

```
if ask.lower() == 'open':
    with open(filename, 'r') as f:
        contents = f.read().splitlines()

    search_name = input("What is your name? ")
    for line in contents:
        if line.find(search_name) != -1:
            print(line)
        else:
            print("Unable to find your name")
```

output:

Unable to find your name
Unable to find your name

Comment: Check your input file, there could be more than one line present in it. Something like an empty line could be there in the file.

Comment: You can just use `f.readlines()` instead of `f.read().splitlines()`

Comment: You might want to check if *line* has any significant content

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a more robust construct:

```
if ask.lower() == 'open':
    with open(filename) as f:
        name = input('What is your name? ')
        for line in f:
            if name in line:
                print(line)
                break
        else:
            print('Unable to find your name')
```

Comment: I agree. Anyhow, both of your answers helped me and this one is just more direct and concise.

Answer (score -1):

You are invoking the `print` command for every entry in your file!
Let me clarify, for the name that you get as input into `search_name`, you are looping over EVERY LINE that you have read from a file (in your case it seems that the file had 2 lines).

Your if cluase is not what you want. What you need is something like this:

```
if ask.lower() == 'open':
     with open(filename, 'r') as f:
        contents = f.read().splitlines()

search_name = input("What is your name? ")
is_found = false
for line in contents:
    if line.find(search_name) != -1:
        is_found = true
        print(line)

if not is_found:
    print("Unable to find your name")
```

Comment: I'm very surprised that this has been accepted as the definitive answer. Consider what happens if ask.lower() != 'open'